# Switching between live/ recorded playback modes

Tags: gui-design, mobile

The mobile surveillance app I'm working with has two modes: Live mode and Recorded mode.

**Live mode** streams 4 camera feeds and allows the user to control their PTZ (pan, tilt, zoom) functions.

**Recorded video mode** is similar looking but the PTZ function is replaced with playback, speed, and date picker options

I have two ideas for switching modes:

1. Navigation tabs that just switch the page

-or-

2. A search icon that "pulls up" a toolbar from the bottom

**Which one works better for switching between these modes? Is there a different way to switch modes that I'm not thinking of?**

[image]

Comment: Why do the pan/tilt controls and the playback controls appear at the video listing level in the wireframes? Should they not appear only when watching a single feed or recorded video?

Comment: PTZ wouldn't be possible during recorded video playback. But yes, it should only appear when one camera is being viewed.

Comment: Option 1 is better, I would replace "Search" with "Recorded". So it will be clear for the user LIVE vs RECORDED.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd prefer the navigation tabs approach, but if there are just two possible modes you could simplify it by **just giving the option to select the mode in which you are not positioned**.

[image]